# How to remove pager and sorter on home page Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I'm trying to modify mi **CMS/home_page** of Magento. I want to see some products that are on a specific category, like this:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="35" column_count="4" template="catalog/product/list.phtml" }}
```

It shows the category products, but now, I want to go a step further, and I want to remove some elements as it is the home page. I attach an image to clarify:

[image: Remove elements]

1 and 2 are located at the **pager** element. When we have more than one page of products, we can also see the **pages** (element 4), also located here. In this case, we only have 4 products, so we don't see the pages.
Element 3 is at **sorter** element.

I want to remove element 1, 2 and 3 if it's the home page, but keep element 4 (the pages).

Any idea on how can I do that on Magento?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve it. For anyone who could need it, without a payed extension, here I write what I did:

**First:**

I duplicated this phtml on my theme folder:

```
catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml
catalog/product/list.phtml
```

And I paste them on my template folder. I changed the name in order to not override the elements for the other pages that  are not the home page.

```
catalog/product/list/toolbar_home.phtml
catalog/product/list_home.phtml
```

With this, I have 2 phtml that work only for my homepage. How do I call them?

**Second:**

I add the specific block on my home page:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="35" column_count="4" template="catalog/product/list_home.phtml" }}
```

**Beware:** I changed the template to point to my template.

**Third:**

On my list_home.phtml, where you can find this code:

```
<?php echo $this->getToolbarHtml() ?>
```

I changed it by this:

```
<?php echo $this->getToolbarHtmlHome() ?>
```

This function doesn't exist, so we need to create it. This function will call our **toolbar_home.phtml**.

**Fourth:**

Go to **code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List.php**, and find the function **getToolbarHtml**. Copy and paste it under it. And change it to look like this:

```
public function getToolbarHtmlHome()
{
    return $this->getChildHtml('toolbar_home');
}
```

Now that we have created all the code, you can go to **template/catalog/product/list/toolbar_home.phtml** and modify whatever you want. It will work only on your home page! :)

Comment: `Beware: I changed the template to point to my template.`  ..  Like I said, if you don't want to edit the core or template, z-blocks are perfect.

Comment: Yes, thank to you, I could arrive to this solution! Thanks a lot!  :D

Answer (score 1):

You will have to duplicate the category product list display module, which means creating your own module, XML, PHTML and such ...  Personally I would use the `z-blocks` module from [Aheadworks](http://ecommerce.aheadworks.com/magento-extensions/z-blocks.html).  This will give you the ability do display things like "featured products" etc. on your homepage without editing Magento block code. ..  It's not that expensive considering the amount of time you will spend developing what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

As you may already be knowing that these elements are being rendered through pager.phtml.
 The elements that you want to remove can made to disappear by checking for a condition i.e
if(!(Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getIdentifier()=='home'))
{pass the variables that you do not want to appear in home page}